# Zend v1 and angular-js - error with Zend_session after upgrade php 5.2 to 5.6

Tags: angularjs, zend-framework

In my site I use angular.
And in code of angular use:

```js
$http.post('laboratory.php?action=api/laboratory/assay&type=json&id=' + id, {LaboratoryAssay: data}).success(callback);
```

So, in php 5.2 with Zend_Session class this work Ok!

But after upgrade to 5.6 I see
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Session_Exception' with message 'Session must be started before any output has been sent to the browser; output started in /0' in D:\htdocs\develop\winner\Zend\Session.php:454

I think that it's php://input, but in PHP 5.2 work fined.
If I not post {LaboratoryAssay: data} - in request of angular - it's work!
But I need {LaboratoryAssay: data} in request.

How I can patched it?

Comment: O, now I test it in php 5.6.16 - work! But in 5.6.24 - not work )) Why?

Comment: O sorry,, mistake in first comment -  now I test it in php 5.6.16 with xdebuger - and it's work, but if I exlude xdebuger in php.ini - not work)) ? Why?